# Rotating co-ordinates in 3D

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, rotations, spherical-coordinates

Suppose I have 3 axes, $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that $x$ is horizontal, $y$ is vertical, and $z$ goes in/out of the computer screen where $+$ve values stick out and $-$ve values are sunken in.

Suppose I have a spherical co-ordinate system where $r$ is the radius from the origin $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$, $\theta$ is the rotation about the $x$ axis and $\phi$ is the rotation about the $y$ axis, such that $(r,\theta,\phi)=(1,0,0) \mapsto (x, y, z) = (0, 0, 1)$. Assume that I rotate about $y$ first, *then* about $x$.

I have a number of points, each of which has an associated $r, \theta, \phi$, and a world $\Theta,\Phi$. Imagine the points exist in space and we're looking at them from a camera, and depending on how the world $\Theta,\Phi$ changes, the camera is looking at the origin from a different point.

Basically, I'm trying to render some objects on a computer in a roughly spherical arrangement, and allow the user to rotate the view.

*Sort of like those animated, interactive keyword clouds you sometimes see on the Internet where you move the mouse and the keywords move around in a spherical arrangement.*

First I calculate each point's ($p_i$) original $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$ like so:

\begin{align}
x_i &= r_i * sin(\phi_i) * cos(\theta_i) \\
y_i &= r_i * sin(\theta_i) \\
z_i &= r_i * cos(\phi_i) * cos(\theta_i)
\end{align}

Then, I rotate the original $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ by the world $\Theta$ first about the $y$ axis:

\begin{align}
x_i &:= cos(\Phi) * x_i - sin(\Phi) * z_i \\
y_i &:= y_i \\
z_i &:= sin(\Phi) * x_i + cos(\Phi) * z_i 
\end{align}

Then about the $x$ axis:

\begin{align}
x_i &:= x_i \\
y_i &:= cos(\Theta) * y_i + sin(\Theta) * z_i \\
z_i &:= cos(\Theta) * z_i - sin(\Theta) * y_i 
\end{align}

I then render each point $p_i$ at co-ordinates $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$.

The problem is, as long as I only apply *one* of the two world rotations - either $\Theta$ or $\Phi$, everything is rendered correctly. As soon as I apply both rotations together, as the interactive image is displayed with $\Theta$ and $\Phi$ changing, the objects get distorted, as though they're being sheared into a plane, and then back to their original spherical arrangement again.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: your $r,\theta,\phi$ seem to be different from the standard math usage. Perhaps if you link to or add a figure it could help.

Comment: @Maesumi $x$ is left/right, $y$ is up/down, $z$ is in/out. $\theta$ is rotation about the $x$ axis, and $\phi$ is rotation about the $y$ axis. $y$-rotation is applied first, then $x$-rotation. I don't have a figure illustrating this, but it shouldn't be too complicated?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a typo but on your second set of equations you have $x_i$ in terms of $x_i$ and $z_i$, while $z_i$ is in terms of $x_i$ and $y_i$ instead of $z_i$.

Comment: @Maesumi Thanks! You're right - but it was just a typo in my question. My code had the correct equations.

Comment: That is what I thought. Now in your second paragraph you say $\theta$ is rotation angle about $x$ axis. This is very confusing to me. So let's make sure we are talking about the same thing. Your first set of equations look like spherical coordinate formulas. Except for your formula for $y_i$. Are you using spherical coordinates? e.g. [as in here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). If so let me know how you relabel the first picture there to get yours.

Comment: @Maesumi Changing the first picture on that page to mine: $z \mapsto y$, $y \mapsto x$, $x \mapsto z$, $\phi \mapsto \theta$ and $\theta \mapsto \phi$ with the (my) $y$-axis rotation first, and the (my) $x$-axis rotation second.

Comment: Now I am more confused! If  I take (1) your mapping in the last comment (2) that you mean to map from spherical into Cartesian coordinates in your first set of triple equations then I think your transformations should be $y=r\cos \phi, x=r \sin \phi \sin theta, z=r \sin \phi \cos \theta$, moreover $(r,\theta,\phi)=(1,0,0)$ will map  to $(x,y,z)=(0,1,0)$.

Comment: Is it really essential that you use this unusual spherical coordinate system?  There's nothing wrong with it, but I think people would feel more comfortable with the standard angles--rotating about the $y$-axis by $\theta$ and then rotating about the $z$-axis by $\phi$. Regardless, how do you apply both rotations on $\Phi, \Theta$ "together"?  Do you do one first and then the other?  Are you changing $\Theta, \Phi$ dynamically (with time) to achieve time-varying rotations?

Comment: I have been told that there are two competing standards for spherical coordinates - apparently physicists prefer $(r,\phi,\theta)$ for what mathematicians call $(r,\theta,\phi)$. (Or vice versa, I can't remember.) So let's not get too hung up on the choice of notation.

Comment: Are you overwriting $x_i$ before updating $z_i$? That would be a mistake.